# Matplotlib, animation by points in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, matplotlib, animation

I want to have a list of points like

```
list = [[1.0, 1.0], ... ,[17.3, 39.4]]
```

and I want to make an animation in matplotlib, where my object would in first frame be in the first point the second frame in second point, and so on and on...

How would I do this?

I just want to know the general idea.. the most basic code possible, because I am new to this python library.

Comment: Lots of nice examples [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/index.html#animation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
from IPython.display import HTML

# list of points
lst = [
       [1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 2.0], [1.0, 3.0], [1.0, 4.0], [1.0, 5.0],
       [2.0, 5.0], [3.0, 5.0], [4.0, 5.0], [5.0, 5.0], [5.0, 4.0],
       [5.0, 3.0], [5.0, 2.0], [5.0, 1.0], [4.0, 1.0], [3.0, 1.0],
       [2.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0]
]

# resolve max values for x and y axes
max_x = max([pt[0] for pt in lst]) + 1
max_y = max([pt[1] for pt in lst]) + 1

# create figure and set limits
fig = plt.figure()
plt.xlim(0, max_x)
plt.ylim(0, max_y)

# create graph
graph, = plt.plot([], [], 'o')

# hide figure
plt.close()

# define function for animation
# it sets point coordinates based an frame number
def animate(i):
    graph.set_data(lst[i][0], lst[i][1])
    return graph

# init FuncAnimation
ani = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=len(lst), interval=200, repeat=False)

# is needed to make animation available in jupiter / colab
HTML(ani.to_jshtml())
```